Pandas DataFrame Cannot use assign function - Why?
I am encountering some odd behavior in pandas, and I am hoping someone could shed some light on specifics from the df.assign(...) function in a pandas dataframe. I am getting a ValueError when trying to assign to column, despite the function being valid.
def is_toc_row(row):
    m_sig = m_df.loc[m_df.signature == row.signature]
    pct = (~pd.isnull(m_sig.line_type)).sum() / m_sig.shape[0]
    return (not pd.isnull(row.line_type)) or (pct < .5)


m_df = m_df.assign(is_toc_row=is_toc_row)

Gives:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

But this works totally fine:
for ind, row in m_df.iterrows():
    m_df.at[ind, 'is_toc_row'] = is_toc_row(row)

Is there some issue with referencing the rest of the DataFrame in the function? All I see in the docs is that the subject df cannot change, which it does not.
Of course I am capable of building a workaround, I just want to understand why this does not work for future use.
A few rows of data



index
signature
line_type




0
WYcxXTjq27YAP4uJOcLeRLelyUixNJaOwFwf2qqfpM4
NaN


1
WYcxXTjq27YAP4uJOcLeRLelyUixNJaOwFwf2qqfpM4
NaN


2
WYcxXTjq27YAP4uJOcLeRLelyUixNJaOwFwf2qqfpM4
1


3
WYcxXTjq27YAP4uJOcLeRLelyUixNJaOwFwf2qqfpM4
2


4
WYcxXTjq27YAP4uJOcLeRLelyUixNJaOwFwf2qqfpM4
2.4




is_toc_row = is_toc_row?

@EmiOB I believe the intent here is that column named "is_toc_row"` should be assigned the value of calling the method "is_toc_row"

I've tried using assign and calling a function in the same way you have, and get no error. I would suggest that the error is in your function rather than assign.

A small minimal reproducible example of your data would help us tell you what. probably the .loc line in your function though

row isn't a row here. See the docs: "[callables] are computed on the DataFrame". That's the problem.

Actually when assign is used with a custom function, the function doesn't receive the datafame row by row (like apply) but receives once the full dataframe. Let's take a toy example:
m_df = pd.DataFrame({'temp_b': [7.0, 5.0], 'temp_c': [17.0, 25.0]},
                     index=['Portland', 'Berkeley'])

def myfunc(x):
    print(x, "*end*")
    return  x.temp_c + x.temp_b

m_df = m_df.assign(is_toc_row=myfunc)
display(m_df)



Thank you! I don't know why I felt so confident that it was iterated. I think because the docs warned against the dataframe changing.

Assign also supports lambda use: m_df.assign(is_toc_row = lambda df: df["temp_c"].add(df["temp_b"]))

I think your error is coming from a line in your function, rather than assign itself (more info on your error can be found in this answer), as I have tried using assign with a simple function example and have no issues:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Bar':[6,7,8,9,10]})
   Foo  Bar
0    1    6
1    2    7
2    3    8
3    4    9
4    5   10

Function to assign:
def function(x):
    return x['Foo'] * x['Bar']

Then to assign the output of this as new_col using:
df.assign(new_col = function)

Which outputs:
   Foo  Bar  new_col
0    1    6        6
1    2    7       14
2    3    8       24
3    4    9       36
4    5   10       50

